# Unable to load http URL Image in TestFlight Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, testflight

I have my app on TestFlight but none of the images are showing. 
How can I troubleshoot an app from TestFlight? 
is there anything I'm missing on my info.pls 
I see all the images when I am debugging on my device or simulators, all images are ok.

I'm using https for all remote images and using this one as an example https://i.picsum.photos/id/52/200/300.jpg

also added NSAllowArbitraryLoad just in case but is not working either.

settings for deployment are (I tried Managed as well) not sure if this is related 
[image]

Comment: you can view your app logs from your device using XCode, and/or you can use a logging and crash reporting service like appcenter.ms

Comment: but the app is not crashing, that's the issue is just not showing my images? but they show when I debug

Comment: "**LOGGING** and crash reporting"

Comment: all I see is the string and it works fine under any browser. is there anything particular or new that needs to be added to the info.pls to allow images?

Comment: are these remote images from a url, or local images stored as resources, etc?  If they are remote images are they using https?  You have not included any useful information in your post that we could use to help you.

Comment: this one https://i.picsum.photos/id/52/200/300.jpg . They all use https like the example. I just published that image just to  test if it was from my source  but is from all remote images.

Comment: I would say upload your ipa again is the safer solution. It should work if it works when you debug. Check if you have made any change or try some different images.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT , I uploaded like 10 times and I even try public images on google. it is so strange none of the images show once it gets to them.

Comment: Does it work if you install the ipa package(which you will upload to itunes) through itunes? Does you install your app under a release mode when you test it on your iphone?

Comment: I was using APPCENTER for the release using continuous integration. then I decided to test the publishing manually and the images worked as expected. Now I am more confused because using app center the app gets to TESTFLIGHT without any warnings.

Comment: No idea what happen with the testflight version, the ipa file should be same before and after you upload.